# what is the current object referred to while calling collections.sort() method inside a class which implements Comparable interface?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

```
public class TestSort3{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        ArrayList<Student> al=new ArrayList<Student>();  
        al.add(new Student(101,"Vijay",23));  
        al.add(new Student(106,"Ajay",27));  
        al.add(new Student(105,"Jai",21));  

        Collections.sort(al);  
        for(Student st:al){  
            System.out.println(st.rollno+" "+st.name+" "+st.age);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The definition of `compareTo` is stated as :

```
class Student implements Comparable <Student> {
    int rollno;
    String name;
    int age;
    Student(int rollno, String name, int age) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int compareTo(Student st) {
        if (age == st.age)
            return 0;
        else if (age > st.age)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

I am unable to get the logic by which age is compared inside `compareTo` method. When `Collections.sort()` method is called , `compareTo()` will be called and we have passed the instance of `ArrayList`, so it takes an instance of `Student` class is passed, now which is the other `Student` instance with which it is compared?

I have already gone through other stackoverflow links related to this method, but I am unable to get my doubt clarified, please clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Every student object will be compared with other student object in
  your list.
- So when one student object age will be compared with other student object age that is passed as a parameter in compareTo method.

Let us say we have three students as below.

```
Student vijay = new Student(101, "vijay", 23);
Student ajay= new Student(106, "Ajay", 27); 
Student jai= new Student(105, "jai", 21);
```

- you have a student `vijay` i.e. `new Student(101,"Vijay",23)`
- `compareTo()` method is being called in `vijay`, it will be compared with `ajay` that is defined by `new Student(106,"Ajay", 26 )`.
- `compareTo()` method is impelemented in such way that `age` will be compared and `vijay` will be logically less than `Ajay`.
- returning 0 means objects are logically equal
- returning negative integer means `this` object is less than object passed to `compareTo` method.
- returning positive integer means `this` object is logically greater than object passed to `compareTo()` method.

Overall, 
 - `vijay` will be compared with `ajay` and due to our implementation, `vijay` is logically less than `ajay`.
 - `ajay` will be compared with `jai`and `ajay` will be logically greater than `jai`

This kind of process will happen for elements with all combinations and final result will be in increasing order of age, i.e. `jai < vijay < ajay`

There are different sorting algorithms implemented in java which will be selected based on certain scenario which are irrelevant to our question.

Comment: So it's like selection sort implementation which takes O(n^2) time right ?

Answer (score 2):

`this` simply referes to the object on which `compareTo` gets called. In the case of the call to `Collections.sort` that might be any of the members of the collection.

To make it less abstract:

In order to use `compareTo`, it has to get called like this:

```
a.comparTo(b)
```

where both `a` and `b` are instances of `Student`. `Collections.sort` does exactly that (Although the actual call seems to be in `[Arrays.mergSort][1]`). The details which instance gets used depend on the the sorting algorithm implemented and the initial order of elements in the collection.